# position absolute and relative problem in ie7

Tags: css

There is a div with toggle behavior for toggling the div there is an image at the bottom right of the div to place the image to bottom right i am making the parent div position relative and setting the image position absolutely but the problem arises when i am clicking the image to toggle on toggle up the image is staying at the bottom and on toggle down it is going to the top this behavior is only in ie 7 in ie8 firefox chrome it is behaving fine

the css is somewhat like this

```
 .filterPanel
{
 border: 1px solid #fbcb09 ;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-khtml-border-radius: 5px;
border-radious: 5px;
 position: relative;
 margin: 0;
 padding:0;
 z-index: 1;
}
.toggleCollapse, .toggleExpand
{
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 3px;

    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #FBCB09;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 2px 1px 2px 2px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -10px;
    right:5px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

filter panel is the parent div and toggleCollapse is the image that iam talking about it is inside this div(filter panel) how to fix this

Comment: Try using a colon once in a while.

Comment: You need to provide either a proper test case using a site such as [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/), or a link to the live page. It's difficult parse CSS and imagine your HTML as IE7 would with our brains.

Comment: well i know that but its in local host, if someone can suggest me some other way to put the image at the bottom right other than this position absolute and relative trick

Comment: You're unlikely to get a good answer without doing what I suggested. Try making a version of your page using [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/).

Comment: on adding overflow hidden in the filterpanel it is behaving fine but causing some z-index problem that is half of the image is hiding under the div

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but negative margins and relative positions get icky in IE's.

Consider a different approach: To put your toggleCollapse button on the bottom, forget the position: relative business put the button AFTER the div you are toggling and set it's position to relative, top: -10px (or whatever).

EG:

```
<div class="filter_wrapper">
<div class="filter_panel">Some stuff</div>
<a class="toggle">[ toggle me ]</a>
</div>
```